# passing function pointer in c with a pointer argument

Tags: c

Here, I have defined two function pointers `func1` and `func2`, and I guess this a way to use function pointers in c.But my question is when I call

```
executor(func1);
executor(func2);
```

How can I allocate memory for `uint8_t *` and pass it as an argument for either `func1` and `func2`, so that I can use it back in main()

```
typedef int (*FUNC_PTR)(uint64_t, uint8_t*);

void executor(FUNC_PTR func)
{ 
   uint64_t opts = 0x0000010;
   uint8_t val = 0;
   res = func(opts, &val);
}

int func1(uint64_t a, uint8_t* b)
{ 
   //do some stuff

}

int func2(uint64_t a, uint8_t* b)
{ 
//do some stuff
}

void main()
{
   executor(func1);
   executor(func2);
}
```

Comment: Your `executor` needs to take some extra argument(s) which will get passed to `func` and let the caller worry about the allocation.. Or use some global/static/dynamically allocated buffers. Which I would not recommend...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it to the argument list of `executor`.

```
void executor(FUNC_PTR func, uint8_t* b)
{ 
   uint64_t opts = 0x0000010;
   res = func(opts, b);
}
```

You can allocate the memory on the stack or heap in main.

```
void main()
{
   uint8_t mem1, mem2;
   executor(func1, &mem1);
   executor(func2, &mem2);
}
```

Comment: Also, is there any way to just not pass any function, for example executor(void) something like that?

Comment: @pavikirthi, I'm not sure I understand that question; I'd suggest asking a new question that specifies exactly what behavior you'd want if you passed in no arguments.

Comment: Sure! Thank you